# Can any collection of numbers be considered as a vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let's assume I am considering a collection of numbers - $A=[1,7,6,3,4,7]$. So can $A$ be considered as a vector. And if yes then will will any collection of numbers could be considered as a vector ??

Comment: well yes and no, you can say it is a vector but usually vector is an element in a vector space so something is missing...

Comment: @yanko So can we say that any collection of numbers could be a part of a vector space ?

Comment: You can consider every $n$-tuple as a vector in $\mathbb R_n$, even if $A$ has countable infinite many elements, you can consider it as a vector in the infinite-dimensional space.

Comment: Incidentally, *anything* can be considered as a vector -- the relevant question is usually whether it can be considered as a vector in a useful way.

Answer (score 2):

The word "vector" is used with slightly different meanings. In computer science it is sometimes synonymous to "list". So it that case, yes!

But most often it means "element of a vector space". So if by "number" you mean "real number", ie "element of $\mathbb{R}$", then yes, any such tuple can bee seen as a vector, because it is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n$ (finite or infinite) is the length of the tuple. $\mathbb{R}^n$ can naturally be given the structure of a vector space (it is a product space of $\mathbb{R}$). So in this case, again yes!

Answer (score 0):

Calling something a vector strongly implies it's membership in a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), which is a full algebraic structure as well as merely a combination of numbers. That's a lot of additional information which should be present to call something a vector.

However given two sets with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ then I can define a *tuple* $(a,b)$ to be an element of the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) $A \times B$. This way we can build up arbitrary collections of ordered lists of set elements. If I had a product of $n$ sets then I'd call that an *n-tuple*.

Also, if we restrict ourselves to the idea of number we can consider [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) over a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) as well. Since the integers form a ring but not a field we can still analogously use some of the techniques from linear algebra in this more general setting.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this answer as the word "vector" has meanings outside of it's usual mathematical definition. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector. The first entry under computer science is "A one-dimensional array" which is very close to the OP's understanding of it. To give the usual mathematical definition is good, but don't imply that this is the only definition.

Comment: The cartesian product is usually defined as the set of tuples, thus the latter defines the former, not the other way around. Tuples are usually defined as certain sets in axiomatic set theory, so it's a bit tricky. An approach where the cartesian products is defined by its universal property is possible, and then taking tuples to mean elememts of a given product is possible but it too is a bit subtle. It is important to understand that unlike union or intersection, the cartesian product is fundamentally different.

Comment: @JensRenders The mathematical definition seems correct given this is mathexchange. If they wanted a more pedestrian interpretation it begs the question as to why the asked it here.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I'm accustomed to seeing members of the cartesian product being described as anything other than ordered pairs which are in turn used to definite what is meant by tuple. I'd be curious to see any references you have that being with the definition of a tuple as I've never seen that presentation before.

Comment: @CyclotomicField agreed, so give that, but don't imply there are no others. Also note that I said "usual mathematical definition" the other definitions are in many cases also mathematical definitions and by the way, computer science and mathematics largely coincide (it is almost a subset even), so these other definitions are certainly worth mentioning on this site

Comment: @CyclotomicField see Kuratowski's definition of ordered pair.